# ASP.NET MVC5 CHECK IF ID IS SET C#

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, asp.net-mvc-5, readonly

I am working in asp.net mvc5 view , how to know if id is written in the textbox , here ,How to know if Id is written here and save that value for another use ??? How to know if id is already set in the textbox ?

Comment: Tidy your question up and clarify it please. You keep repeating yourself, and the formatting is poor.

Comment: @ADyson THANKS SIR , I HAVE ALREADY EDITED THE QUESTION

Comment: please don't use capitals, it is regarded as shouting when written online, and some people might think it's rude. I will forgive it since I presume you didn't know :-)

Comment: Anyway, to address your question, I think you are asking about validation rules? You want it so that an error will show if the Id field is not completed? I don't know for sure, your wording is unclear. Try to be more specific. Anyway Please show your model class. Did you set a `[Required]` attribute on the ID field?

Comment: Hi sir ,  , lets forget a minute about model validation , i just want to know if user has already write something in ID eDITOR FIELD , if for example he wrote HAHAHA on ti , i want to save that value HAHAHA into a variable for something else .. ID is a string ..i just want to show that HAHAHA as readonly field in the create view

Comment: P.S. If I was you I would stop addressing people online as "Sir", because you can never be certain of their gender. And also you still need to change the capitalised words.

Comment: i am very new to this forum , thanks again

Comment: The advice about language use would apply anywhere on the internet, not just this site :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the if conditional the wrong way:

Instead of writing

```
@if (Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id) !=null){  SHOW id}
```

Write

```
@if (model.Id != null) { 
 display Id here
}
```

You can read more about conditionals here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor

**UPD** You can use javascript to display text written by a user on the fly. There's a good example here on how to do it with jQuery - http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/handling-text-changed-event-in-aspmvc-3-with-jquery

```
 <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Id').change(function () {
        // set value into label
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sir , lets be clear again , i am in the create view so i am about to create a new entity that does not exist and doesnt have already an ID , lets pretend the user is filling all the fields in the view ID TITLE and so on , i want that ON THE FLY to do that , if the user writes something in the ID Editor field ,ID is a string and lets say he wrote HAHAHA as ID , now i want to have that value to have that 'HAHAHA' and show in the view as readonly text ..so inside the create view  @if (Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id) !=null){  SHOW what user wrote in ID field}

Comment: @tringatringa this should be the text of your question, much clearer. You can't do that job with Razor because Razor only runs before the page loads (it is what is used to construct the final page). If you want to do something while the user is entering text into the fields then you need some Javascript which detects when the user has finished writing in the box (i.e. when it loses focus), gets the content of the field and writes it into a label. BTW, if you are creating an entity, really the database should be setting its ID, not the user, otherwise you can't guarantee unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks so much sir for explaining this and sorry from my bad english :$ . can you explain how can i achieve that by javascript , what i want is to create a link inside the view like this (on the fly ) :      @Html.ActionLink("Details1", "Details1", new { id = Model.Id })  and this Id is automatically filled with the text that user writes in the ID FIELD , ID is a string , and let forget a little about validation , constratins and so on:)

Comment: "create a link inside the view like this (on the fly ) : @Html.ActionLink("Details1", "Details1", new { id = Model.Id }) ". Why would you want that?? The entity doesn't exist until you submit the form and save it, so this link, if you created it, would lead nowhere. And again, you cannot guarantee at this moment that the ID has not already been taken by another previously existing entity, so it's a bad idea all round. However, if you insist on this flawed design, the edit to this answer provides you with how to detect when the field has been modified.

Comment: hmmm well you convinced me with this explanation , i will close this disscusion here , thanks a lot